# Инициализация в конструкторе и наследование

Tags: javascript, java

Дан следующий код:

```
public class InheritanceInitOrder {
static class A {
    String a;
    A() {
        a = "a";
        System.out.println("a initialized");
        System.out.println("b=" + ((B)this).b);
    }
}

static class B extends A {
    String b;
    B() {
        b = "b";
        System.out.println("b initialized");
        System.out.println("b=" + b);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    new B();
}    
}
```

Не могу понять, как работает строчка:

```
System.out.println("b=" + ((B)this).b);
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А с чем тут сложность? Ссылку на текущий объект `this` в явном виде приводим к классу `B` и обращаемся к его полю `b`.

Но поскольку это конструктор класса `A`, поле `b` еще не проинициализировано (конструктор `B` еще не отработал), и мы получим в консоли `"b=null"`.

За пределами учебного коде так делать, разумеется, не стоит:

- Во-первых, это нарушает основные принципы ООП: родительский класс знает подробности реализации своих наследников.
- Во-вторых, в таком виде при попытке создать экземпляр `new A()` программа свалится на исключении.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то в строчке кода 

    new B();    

мы выделяем память в Heap'e на объект, и поэтому такое приведение возможно? 
В то же время, создавая объект А, никаких подробностей о классе В нет, и поэтому ошибка, так? Спасибо.

Comment: @Remind, да, именно так.